# JQuery - Change File Name Property

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is to change the name property of a file using JQuery.
I am getting an id from an ajax response and I want to set the name property of an uploaded file to that value.

```
success: function(data){
    var fileData = $("#image").prop('files')[0];
    fileData.name = data[0].id;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', fileData);
}
```

However, when I check the uploaded file, the name doesn't change, it still has what its name when it was first uploaded. Am I doing it properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot, I used the count and glob function in the Php side. No need to change the name of the file using JQuery.

```
$imageCount = count(glob("/imageDirectory/*.jpg"));
$imageName = $imageCount + 1;
```

And then append the $imageName variable to the move_uploaded_file function. The main concern here is its performance when the volume of files increase.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "/upload/".$imageName.".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should give it a name when you are appending it to the form.

```
success: function(data){
    var fileData = $("#image").prop('files')[0];
    fileData.name = data[0].id;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(data[0].id, fileData); // Like here
}
```